# Resize & thumb function works, except when uploading multiple files

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, image-uploading

For some reason my resize & thumbnail function only works with one file.

When I try to upload more files, for example 3, it only processes the first file correctly.
It saves it in my directory, resizes it, puts on a watermark and inserts the paths into my database.
The second file is only saved and resized, no thumbnail is saved and it's paths aren't inserted into my database.
The third file doesn't get processed at all and the page won't return to it's original (which it should, and display an array of the images that are uploaded).

If I comment out the thumbnail function so that it only runs the watermark/resize function, it only processes the first two files and will only put the first file into the database. Page won't return to it's original state.
If I comment out the watermark/resize function, so that it only runs the thumbnail function, it only processes the first file untill the thumbnail function (so it saves the original but won't resize it to a thumbnail and won't put an entry into the database). Page won't return to it's original state.
If I comment out both the functions, it uploads the 3 files correctly and saves the paths into the database. The page returns to it's original state.

What am I doing wrong?

index.php:

```
<?php

include "include/resize.php";

$file_dest = "photos/orig/";
$thumb_dest = "photos/thumbs/";

if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name'][0])){

    $files = $_FILES['files'];

    $uploaded = array();
    $bestanden = array();
    $failed = array();

    $allowedExt = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif');

    foreach($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {
        $file_tmp = $files['tmp_name'][$position];
        $file_size = $files['size'][$position];
        $file_error = $files['error'][$position];

        $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
        $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

        if(in_array($file_ext, $allowedExt)){

            if($file_error == 0){

                if($file_size <= 32000000){

                    $file_name_new = uniqid('', true)."_".$file_name;
                    $file_move = $file_dest.$file_name_new;

                    if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_move)){
                        $uploaded[$position]['naam'] = $file_name;
                        $uploaded[$position]['pad'] = $file_move;

                        $path_web = 'photos/web/'.$file_name_new;
                        $path_thumb = 'photos/thumb/'.$file_name_new;
                        watermark_image($file_move, $path_web);
                        create_thumbnail($file_move, $path_thumb, 150, 150);

                        include "include/config.php";
                        $query = "INSERT INTO galerij (name, category, orig, web, thumb, folio) VALUES ('$file_name', '', '$file_move', '', '', '')";
                        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

                    }else{
                        $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] failed to upload.";
                    }

                }else{
                    $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] is too large.";
                }

            }else{
                $failed[$position] = "[P$file_name}] errored with code {$file_error}";
            }

        }else{
            $failed[$position] = "[{$file_name}] file extension '{$file_ext}' is not allowed.";
        }
    }

    if(!empty($uploaded)){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($uploaded);
        echo "</pre>";

    }

    if(!empty($failed)){
        print_r($failed);
    }

}else{
    echo "No files were added.";
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Tutorial</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tut.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="uploaded">
<?php


?>
</div>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple id="file"/><p>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit" />
    </div>
</form>

<div id="upload_progress"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

resize.php:

```
<?php
    function watermark_image($file, $destination){

        $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('images/watermerk.png');

        $width = 800;
        $height = 800;

        $source = getimagesize($file);  

        $source_mime = $source['mime']; 


        if($source_mime == 'image/png'){
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            }else if($source_mime == 'image/jpeg'){
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            } else if($source_mime == 'image/gif'){
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            }

        list($file_width, $file_height) = getimagesize($file);

        $file_ratio = $file_width/$file_height;

        if ($width/$height > $file_ratio) {
            $width = $height*$file_ratio;
            } else {
             $height = $width/$file_ratio;
            }

        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $file_width, $file_height);

        $file_x = imagesx($new_image);
        $file_y = imagesy($new_image);

        $logo_x = imagesx($watermark);
        $logo_y = imagesy($watermark);

        $pos_x = 1;
        $pos_y = $file_y - $logo_y + 1;


        imagecopy($new_image, $watermark, $pos_x, $pos_y, 0, 0, $logo_x, $logo_y);
        imagepng($new_image, $destination);

        imagedestroy($new_image);
        imagedestroy($image);
        imagedestroy($watermark);   


/*==============================================================================*/

        function create_thumbnail($path, $save, $width, $height){
            $info = getimagesize($path);
            $size = array($info[0], $info[1]);

            if($info['mime'] == 'image/png'){
                $src = imagecreatefrompng($path);
            }else if($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg'){
                $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
            }else if($info['mime'] == 'image/gif'){
                $src = imagecreatefromgif($path);
            }else{
                return false;
            }


            $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

            $src_aspect = $size[0] / $size[1];
            $thumb_aspect = $width / $height;

            if($src_aspect < $thumb_aspect){

                $scale = $width / $size[0];
                $new_size = array($width, $width / $src_aspect);
                $src_pos = array(0, ($size[1] * $scale - $height) / $scale / 2);

            }else if($src_aspect > $thumb_aspect){

                $scale = $height / $size[1];
                $new_size = array($height * $src_aspect, $height);
                $src_pos = array(($size[0] * $scale - $width) / $scale / 2, 0);
            }else{
                $new_size = array($width, $height);
                $src_pos = array(0, 0);
            }

            $new_size[0] = max($new_size[0], 1);
            $new_size[1] = max($new_size[1], 1);

            imagecopyresampled($thumb, $src, 0, 0, $src_pos[0], $src_pos[1], $new_size[0], $new_size[1], $size[0], $size[1]);

            if($save == false){
                return imagepng($thumb);

            }else{
                return imagepng($thumb, $save);
            }
        }
    }


?>
```

config.php:

```
<?php 

//database credentials
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db('imandra') or die(mysql_error()); 
//echo "Connected to MySQL";
?>
```

SQL query to get the same database:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.9
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Machine: localhost:8889
-- Gegenereerd op: 29 jul 2014 om 22:01
-- Serverversie: 5.5.34-log
-- PHP-versie: 5.5.10

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Databank: `imandra`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `galerij`
--

CREATE TABLE `galerij` (
  `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `orig` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `web` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `thumb` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `folio` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`,`category`,`orig`,`thumb`,`folio`),
  KEY `web` (`web`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Have you checked your `max_execution_time` setting? And do you get any error or warning?

Comment: @Tom Yes, that's 30 seconds but after 6 second it's 'finished' when processing the 3 files. No error or warning in safari, let me check in chrome, just one moment.

Comment: Nope, no errors/warnings in chrome or firefox either.

Comment: You have multiple issues: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), you do not check if the uploads actually succeeded (or if there was an upload at all). You are at least checking if the db stuff failed, but since you're simply assuming success on so many other things, it's kinda like putting a bandaid onto someone's neck after they've been decapitated

Comment: After 6 seconds with all functions enabled? And the error messages should be visible in any browser. You could try setting the log level for your program to E_ALL http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php. Just to be sure there are no filtered messages.

Comment: @MarcB Yeah, the SQL injection stuff I'm planning to put in, but I want it working first. (Currently just working in MAMP) Where should I check for fail/success too, what did I miss?
@ Tom Yes. I'll put the E_ALL in and run it again.

Comment: @Tom: Just put the E_ALL in, but nothing appears.

Comment: I guess your web server has some kind of log file ... is there something in it that could help us here?

Comment: @Tom: I think this could be the issue? PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare create_thumbnail() (previously declared in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imandra/include/resize.php:76) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imandra/include/resize.php on line 76

Comment: Can you try to replace `include "include/resize.php";` with `include_once "include/resize.php";`? But I don't know why this part of code should be executed more than once. Do you include the `resize.php` file somewhere else in your code?

Comment: @Tom: Did it, still the same issue..

Comment: Damn, I'm blind :D. There error is that you declare the function `create_thumbnail()` inside the function `watermark_image()`. If you run that function the second time you redeclare `create_thumbnail` and this causes the error. Make sure you close the function `watermark_image()` correctly before you declare the next one.

Comment: Yeah that was it! Those damn braces haha. Can you post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a redeclaration of the function `create_thumbnail`. This is why it happens:

```
function watermark_image($file, $destination){
    /*
        code
    */  

    function create_thumbnail($path, $save, $width, $height){
        /*
            code
        */
    }
}
```

You declare `create_thumbnail` inside the `watermark_image` function. The parent function will be included once in your code due to the `include` command. If you run the `watermark_image` the first time it will also declare the function `create_thumbnail` for the first time and everything is currently fine. But if you run the parent function again, it tries to declare `create_thumbnail` again and this causes an error.

To fix this you need to declare the sub function as an independent function outside of `watermark_image`:

```
function watermark_image($file, $destination){
    /*
        code
    */
}

function create_thumbnail($path, $save, $width, $height){
    /*
        code
    */
}
```